# What's the algorithm for laying out a circular TreeMap?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, treemap

Given a standard [nested circular treemap](http://www.future-sense.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/ctreemap7.png), how do you calculate the where to place the circles?

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping#The_tiling_algorithm)? and [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Treemap/Algorithms)? Also, is this possibly related to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371869/venn-diagram-generation-software-from-rcc8-specification-or-similar)?

Comment: +1 @MarcoS. Also, [here](http://www.randelshofer.ch/treeviz/) is an implementation in Java (with source code)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem can be described as this: "`Given a set of circles of varying radius, how does one place them within a larger circle, so that none of them overlap`".

It's a hard problem, but here's a brute force solution to get you started:

1. Sort the circles by size
2. Place the largest circle on the inner rim of the bounding circle
3. For the rest of the circles (r1), do the following:

   1. Iterate over all pairs of already placed circles (r2,r3) (including the outer one)
   2. Find the (one or two) points that have distance r1+r2 to the first circle and r1+r3 to the second circle.
   3. Try to place the new circle here.

The above uses the observation that in a perfect packing, every circle must border to at least  two other circles. You can use the algorithm to provide a full search, or you can just iterate randomly and greedily choose the first available spot.